# What does f(-5)=-2 tell me about f(x)

Tags: calculus

As part of a math quiz I was given the following two functions:

f(-5) = -2 and g(x) = -2 * f(x)

The way I interpret the first function is "return -2 regardless of the input" since the right hand side is just a constant.  That would mean that f(x) will also result in -2, making the result of g(x) positive 4.

But I guess I'm missing something because that is not one of the available answers in the quiz.

---

Edit:

Apologies for the unclear question.

The full question in the quiz is as follows:

> If $f(−5) = −2$ and $g(x) = −2 \cdot f(x)$, what point can you determine on the graph of $g$?

I realize now my interpretation was wrong.  Like André said in the comment: I only know the output (-2) of a given input (-5).  Knowing how to read the function f helped me solve the question, thanks guys.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You were given the functions, but what question about the functions did they pose?  It is true that $g(-5)=4$ but that doesn't mean that $g(x)=4$.

Comment: The interpretation of the function $f$ is not right. All the equation says is "return $-2$ on input $-5$." It says nothing about what to return for other inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss understand.

$f$ is a function, say $f$ is $f(x)$. For example consider $f(x)=x+3$,
then $$f(-5)=-5+3=-2$$ but $f$ is not identically $-2$ because for
example $f(0)=3$.

Now, $g(x)=-2f(x)$, for what $x$ can you compute $g(x)$ ?

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation.

Comment: I think the correct word is "misunderstand" and not "miss understand" (who is the daughter of Mr. and Mrs. Understand :-P).